# asp.net mvc inheritance - list parent model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inheritance, parent

I am Using Entity Frameworks and Table per Subclass.
if I have a model Person and children models Instructor and Student for example, how can i list only objects from Person that arent instructor or student?

I have tried .where(m => m.getType() != typeof(Student) ) but it gives me an error "LINQ to entities doesnt recognizes getType method..."

Thanks

Comment: i have tried .where(m => m.getType() != typeof(Student) ) but it gives me an error "LINQ to entities doesnt recognizes getType method..."

Comment: worth updating the question with things you've tried, and their results, so anyone who wants to help knows where to start from.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.OfType<Student>` on your DbSet.

Comment: @codecaster No, entity framework understands it and creates the correct SQL (check in profiler). With table-per-hierarchy it uses the underlying discriminator column. I haven't tried it with table-per-subclass but have no reason to think that would be worse.

Comment: Actually I want only objects from Person that are NOT student or instructor.

Comment: I think you'd need to use a Union for that, i.e. add the ones you DO want rather than exclude the one you don't want.
FWIW, inheritance in EF comes with serious caveats - don't use it unless you have a good reason.